# Opens Sans font renders lower than expected

Tags: android, fonts

I wish to import this [font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) into Android. I'm trying to internationalize my app and this font has some of the characters I need.

This is some of the code I used to create the button, both xml and in the app.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_example
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/example"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

........
Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fonts/OpenSans.ttf);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_example);
button.setTypeface(tf);
.......

}
```

However, it seems that Android renders the font lower than where the font is suppose to lay.

If I took one of those kindergarten lined papers and had to write how the Android device renders the font, I would say it wrote the middle of the character lower than the lowest line on that piece of paper.

My question is why and how do I solve this?